# How to populate radiobutton Group TAB (DocuSign Template) from WebAPI

Tags: docusignapi

I wanted to populate a radio button group TAB in docusign Enveloper Create ->  Composite template for Signers->Tab.

I know how to populate TextBox & Date , Label fields. This is how I am populating TEXTBox successfully for Envelope Create -

```
 var text = new Text { TabLabel = Field.TabName, Value = Field.TabValue };
 textTabs.Add(text);
```

Similarly I successfully populating Email to DocuSign Envelope create

```
 var email = new Email { TabLabel = Field.TabName, Value = Field.TabValue };
 emailTabs.Add(email);
```

Similarly I wanted to know how can I populate radiobutton group / Checkbox group.

Thanks,
Kiroriwal

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a checkbox tab by setting the Selected property to "true" when you create the Checkbox object, similar to how you assigned values to the TabLabel and Value properties in your code above.